# Javascript forEach() skips items

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am new to javascript. Simply i want to remove all objects with completed: true.

But my function doesn't do that. What am i missing ?

```
const todo = [{
    title: 'do this',
    completed: true
},{
    title: 'do this',
    completed: true
},{
    title: 'do this',
    completed: true
},{
    title: 'do this',
    completed: true
}]

const remove = function(todo){
    todo.forEach(function(item,index){      

        if(item.completed){            
            todo.splice(index,1)        
        }
    })

}

remove(todo)
console.log(todo)
```

Comment: If you are going to remove items in a loop, you need to loop over the array backwards otherwise use filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.filter` instead:

```
const undone = todo.filter((item) => !item.completed)
const completed = todo.filter((item) => item.completed)
```